# Swift array of type [SuperClass] with elements of type [Subclass]

Tags: arrays, swift

Can someone explain why this code throws error?

```
class Base {}
class SubclassOfBase: Base {}

let baseItems = [Base](count: 1, repeatedValue: Base())
let subclassItems = [SubclassOfBase](count: 3, repeatedValue: SubclassOfBase())

var items = [Base]()
items.append(SubclassOfBase()) //OK
items.appendContentsOf(baseItems) //OK
items.appendContentsOf(subclassItems) //cannot invoke with argument of type [SubclassOfBase]
items.append(subclassItems.first!) //OK
```

And next question: Is the only way to add subclass elements is by adding them one by one in for loop?

Comment: Possible workaround: `items.appendContentsOf(subclassItems as [Base])`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you check the headers:

```
public mutating func append(newElement: Element)

public mutating func appendContentsOf<C : CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == Element>(newElements: C)
```

Note the difference in type specifiers. While `append` enables you to add anything that is an `Element`, that is, including sublasses, `appendContentsOf` forces you to use an array with exactly the same element type (subclasses not allowed).

It would work with:

```
let subclassItems = [Base](count: 3, repeatedValue: SubclassOfBase())
```

I would consider this to be a bug because this could be easily fixed by improving the function header (well, this also needs an extension to `where` clauses because detecting generic subtypes is impossible right now).

Some possible workarounds:

1. Append directly for every item

   ```
   subclassItems.forEach {items.append($0)}
   ```
2. Declare a helper method for Arrays (will work for `Array`, not for generic `CollectionType`)

   ```
   extension Array {
       public mutating func appendContentsOf(newElements: [Element]) {
           newElements.forEach {
               self.append($0)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Direct cast

   ```
   items.appendContentsOf(subclassItems as [Base])
   ```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you would you fix the function header?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Well, we can't fix it but Apple can. Report it as a bug.

Comment: The `where` clause in a type constraint either requires a type to be _equal_, or conforms to a certain protocol. In the given problem, we would need some new predicate, like _is_a_  type, e.g.: `<C : CollectionType where C.Generator.Element <= Element>`.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Yes, that's the problem. The where clauses are currently a bit limited to handle subtypes.

Comment: or `extension CollectionType  where Generator.Element: Base {``