# How to coerce a Swift array of optionals (nicely)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Using Swift 2.1

I am looking for a nice way to assign an array of non-optional types to an array of optional type, where the type is the same. Here is some of what I have tried:

```
var foos: [Int?] = []
let bars: [Int] = []

foos = bars // Error: Cannot assign value of type '[Int]' to type '[Int?]'
foos = bars as [Int?] // Error: Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to type '[Int?]' in coercion
foos = bars as? [Int?] // Error: 'Int?' is not a subtype of 'Int'
foos = bars.map { $0 } // Works but I think there must be a better way
```

Assigning a non-optional type to an optional type works fine in Swift. I don't understand why this wouldn't also work for an array.

```
var foo: Int? = nil
let bar: Int = 0

foo = bar // Works fine
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you can use flatMap `foos = bars.flatMap{$0}`

Comment: @LeoDabus he's actually trying to to the reverse of what your thinking. He wants to assign a non-optional to an optional using coercion.

Comment: At present, `foos = bars.map { $0 }` seems to be the best solution. The same problem arises if you want to "upcast" an entire array, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256057/swift-array-of-type-superclass-with-elements-of-type-subclass for a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the syntax a little more palatable using a couple of generic functions that will look like type casting:

```
var foos: [Int?]   = []
let bars: [Int]    = []
let fums: [Int64?] = []

func CastArray<T, U>(array:[T?]) -> [U?]
{ return array.map({ $0 as! U? }) } 

func CastArray<T, U>(array:[T]) -> [U?]
{ return array.map({ $0 as? U }) } 

foos = CastArray(bars)
foos = CastArray(fums)
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can use :**
var array3:[Int] = []

var array4 : [AnyObject] = []

array4 = array3

Comment: I would prefer to use the optional type, `AnyObject` would defeat the purpose of strong typing.