# Why can't I cast an array of optionals to a superclass in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to cast an array of `Derived?` to an array of `Base?` but my cast doesn't compile:

```
  1> class Base { }  
  2> class Derived: Base { } 
  3> let x: [Derived?] = [Derived(), Derived()] 
x: [Derived?] = 2 values {
  [0] = 0x0000000100f04970 {
    __lldb_expr_1.Base = {...}
  }
  [1] = 0x0000000100f07580 {
    __lldb_expr_1.Base = {...}
  }
}
  4> let y: [Base?] = x 
repl.swift:4:18: error: cannot convert value of type '[Derived?]' to specified type '[Base?]'
let y: [Base?] = x
                 ^
```

Why doesn't this compile, and how can I achieve this result?

I have this workaround, but it seems a little kludgy:

```
let y: [Base?] = x.map { $0 as Base? }
```

Comment: It's just as your workaround shows: Swift wont infer an array with elements of type `Derived` as _assignable_ directly to an array of of `Base`: you need to do the type conversion on element level. I don't think the `.map` workaround is kludgy at all.

Comment: Similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029470/how-to-coerce-a-swift-array-of-optionals-nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the syntax a little less kludgy by creating a function that will appear to do a type cast:

```
class Base {} 
class Derived: Base {}

func OptionalArray<T, U>(array:[T?]) -> [U?]
{ return array.map({ $0 as! U? }) } 

let x: [Derived?] = [Derived(), Derived()] 
var y: [Base?]    = OptionalArray(x)
```